# Which javascript realisation of getting values from nested tree will be more efficient?

Tags: javascript, tree

I have a nested tree. Under each `<li>` tag I have a string value and an integer value. Which way is more efficient: storing them inside `<li>` options, say integer under "id" option and string under "title", or storing them in a hidden `<input>` values under each `<li>`

I'm using jQuery to find elements in a DOM now, but I'll gladly accept more profitable way, if such exists in native JavaScript.

Comment: I find jQuery "profitable" e.g. it can reduce the development time -- and if it works, why switch? "efficiency" is only needed in-so-far as it can be shown to be "not efficient enough" (where the enough depends upon measurable functional requires)

Answer (score 0):

Try seperating the values into different span classes with semantic class names. You can then use jquery to retrieve the data like

var intVal = $('li span.int-value').text()

Comment: And why is this better than `var intVal = $('li input.int\string').val()`?